# JavaScript raises SyntaxError with data rendered in Jinja template

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to pass data as JSON from a Flask route to a Jinja template rendering JavaScript.  I want to iterate over the data using JavaScript.  The browser shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name.` when `JSON.parse` is called on the rendered data.  How do I use rendered JSON data in JavaScript?

```javascript
var obj = JSON.parse({{ data }})
for (i in obj){
   document.write(obj[i].text + "<br />");
}
```

```python
def get_nodes(node):
    d = {}
    if node == "Root":
        d["text"] = node
    else:
        d["text"] = node.name

    getchildren = get_children(node)
    if getchildren:
        d["nodes"] = [get_nodes(child) for child in getchildren]
    return d

tree = get_nodes("Root")
return render_template("folder.html", data=tree)
```

If I just put `{{ data }}` in the HTML part, what I see looks correct.

```
{'text': 'Root', 'nodes': [{'text': u'Prosjekt3'}, {'text': u'Prosjekt4', 'nodes': [{'text': u'mappe8'}]}]}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flask's Jinja environment automatically escapes data rendered in HTML templates.  This is to avoid security issues if the dev tries to render untrusted user input.

Since you are passing a Python object to be treated as JSON, Flask provides the `tojson` filter which automatically dumps the data to JSON and marks it safe.

```
return render_template('tree.html', tree=tree)
```

```html
var tree = {{ tree|tojson }};
```

When you just look at the data rendered in HTML, it looks correct because the browser displays the escaped symbols as the real symbols (although in this case you're seeing the string representation of a Python dict, not JSON, so there's still some issues like `u` markers).

Previous versions of Flask didn't mark the dumped data safe, so you might come across examples like `{{ tree|tojson|safe }}`, which isn't required anymore.

---

If you're not rendering JSON (or you already dumped the JSON to a string), you can tell Jinja that data is safe to render without escaping by using the `safe` filter.

```
# already dumped to json, so tojson would double-encode it
return render_template('tree.html', tree=json.dumps(tree))
```

```html
var tree = {{ tree|safe }};
```

You can also wrap the string in `Markup` before rendering it, it's equivalent to the `safe` filter.

```
# already dumped and marked safe
return render_template('tree.html', tree=Markup(json.dumps(tree)))
```

```html
var tree = {{ tree }};
```

---

If you're not passing this data to JavaScript, but using it in Jinja instead, you don't need JSON. Pass the actual Python data, don't call `tojson` on it, and use it as you would any other data in the template.

```
return render_template('tree.html', tree=tree)
```

```html
{% for item in tree %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I could archive it using the following code sample.

```
<script>
    console.log(JSON.parse({{json|safe}}))
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

The problem is that your server returns not JSON, but rendered HTML, which escapes some of the symbols with & notation.

Instead of using

```
return render_template("folder.html", data=tree)
```

try

```
return flask.jsonify(**tree)
```