# Passing Python results (array) to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm working with Twitter API on Python to get the current trending hashtags of a city, then I should pass the results (as an array) to my HTML file where I'm working on visualizing the results using JavaScript.

So, I've tried multiple solutions but I thought that flask was yet the easiest.

This is my python code (hashtags.py):

```
import tweepy
import json
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

 consumerKey = "x"
 consumerSecret = "x"
 accessToken = "x"
 accessTokenSecret = "x"

  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("x", "x")
  auth.set_access_token("x", "x")
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

     app = Flask(__name__)
      @app.route('/map/')
      @app.route('/map/<trends>')

    def trend_hash(id):
     for location in api.trends_place(id):
      for trend in location["trends"] :
          print " - %s" % trend["name"]
          trends = trend["name"]

      return render_template("map.html", trends=json.dumps(trends)) 

    trend_hash(1939753)
```

This is my JavaScript code (map.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
   <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/saudiArabiaHigh.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="chartdiv"></div> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 

     var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "map", 
      "dataProvider": { 
      "map": "saudiArabiaHigh", 
      "getAreasFromMap": true }, 
      "areasSettings": { 
      "selectedColor": "#ffffff" }, 
      "listeners": [ {
       "event": "init",
       "method": function (e) {
             var chart = e.chart;

       function getHashtags() {
        var hash = JSON.stringify('{{ trends }}');
        console.log(hash); }

       getHashtags();  }
        }],
           });

     </script>
      </body>
       </html>
```

I tried to watch my console to see if it will print the trending hashtags, but this is what I got:
[image]

it just prints the word (trends) without any results.
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I'm quite positive with the code in python, because I tried to print:

```
render_template("map.html", trends=trends)
```

and it prints map.html with the value of trends.

my problem now is with my script:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please fix the indentation in `hashtags.py` so we can get an idea where you assign values and where you call `render_template`.

But to answer you question:

1. There is no need to use `''` with the variable `{{ trends }}` as you want to pass an object to `JSON.stringify`, not a string.
2. Use the Jinja2's `safe` filter when you pass viriables to the template that you want to preserve.

*map.html:*

```
...
var hash = JSON.stringify({{ trends|safe }});
```

Comment: Just fixed it, and I tried what you said but I'm getting parsing error (unexpected token)

Comment: As suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555383/javascript-raises-syntaxerror-with-json-rendered-in-jinja-template : dont use `json` in your `hashtags.py`but rather use the `tojson` filter in your template. I'll update my answer.

Comment: My problem is in JavaScript I tried to print (render_template("map.html", trends=trends))) and it prints my html file with the trends value. But I keep getting Unexpected token { in my script

Comment: Could you post the whole error output.

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: I noticed that the browser shows the path to the html file in your filesistem. Are you runing the flask development server? If you are not, and you are just opening your html file with the browser the jinjas variables don't get rendered and you browser returns this exact error.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand (development server)? Do you mean the code of Flask?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165479/discussion-between-dasdachs-and-user8393084).