# Still cannot assign a variable from flask to vue.js

Tags: vue.js, flask

Basically what I want to do is to pass variable from flask to vue.js, but nothing seems to be working. So far I've tried a lot of options and suggested idea from [JavaScript raises SyntaxError with data rendered in Jinja template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555383/javascript-raises-syntaxerror-with-data-rendered-in-jinja-template) but my problem is still here. Exactly what I'm trying to do is when passed argument d_var from flask, I want it to be displayed on html(title_variable) using vue.js.

VUE.JS CODE

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
delimiters : ['[[', ']]'],
data: {
    message: "Hello vue! (a dynamic thing)",
    title_variable = {{d_var}},
    indication true,
    j: "You should work harder"
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<p>
  {{ message }}
</p>
<p>
<span v-bind:title="title_variable">
  Show me some text...
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

FLASK

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify, request, flash, 
render_template, 
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    d_var = 'ahahahah'
    return render_template("index.html", title_variable=d_var)


if __name__=="__main__": 
    app.secret_key=os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here...

1. You've set your Vue delimiters to use `[[...]]` so you should use

   ```html
   [[ message ]]
   ```

   in your Vue template
2. Flask is passing `d_var` to `index.html` as `title_variable` so that's what you should use within `{{...}}`, not `d_var`
3. Your JavaScript `data` object isn't valid. You should not be using `=` to assign property values. Try this instead

   ```js
   var app = new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     delimiters : ['[[', ']]'],
     data: {
       message: "Hello vue! (a dynamic thing)",
       title_variable: {{ title_variable|tojson }},
       indication: true,
       j: "You should work harder"
     }
   })
   ```

   See here for information on the `tojson()` filter ~ https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters

Comment: Do you know why I can't output items from list in vue.js when pass list of values from flask?

Comment: Not without seeing code. You should probably create a new question

Comment: @newnick988888 One more thing, it is always preferable to stick to only one template engine, in that case you're using Vue for rendering so you no longer need jinja from flask, see this full CRUD [example](https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-a-single-page-app-with-flask-and-vuejs/).