# How to render a custom Multipolygon in mapbox gl using flask and jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, mapbox-gl-js

another mapbox question from me.

I figured out how to display a custom Polygon on a mapbox map using jinja2. Now I want to take it a step further. I am creating an List of Polygons inside a python flask app. Each item in the List has the following structure:

```
poly = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': []
        }
    }
```

The coordinates are added in the app and look like this:

```
[ [ [-67.13734, 45.13745], [-66.96466, 44.8097], [-68.03252, 44.3252], [-69.06, 43.98], 
[-70.11617, 43.68405], [-70.64573, 43.09008], [-70.75102, 43.08003], [-70.79761, 43.21973],
[-70.98176, 43.36789], [-70.94416, 43.46633], [-71.08482, 45.30524], [-70.66002, 45.46022], 
[-70.30495, 45.91479], [-70.00014, 46.69317], [-69.23708, 47.44777], [-68.90478, 47.18479],
[-68.2343, 47.35462], [-67.79035, 47.06624], [-67.79141, 45.70258], [-67.13734, 45.13745] ] ]
```

The output list looks exactly like the example here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/

So a list of dicts, each dict containing poly.

The hmtl looks like this:

```
<script>
  var features = {{ layers }}

  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [12.940985, 54.063782],
    zoom: 10
  });

  if (features.length > 0) {
  map.addSource('iso', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
          'type': 'FeatureCollection'
          'features': 
              features
      }
  });

  map.addLayer({
      'id': 'iso',
      'type': 'fill',
      // Use "iso" as the data source for this layer
      'source': 'iso',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
          // The fill color for the layer is set to a light purple
          'fill-color': '#088',
          'fill-opacity': 0.8
       }
  });
  } 
});
</script>
```

But when I run the programm, the map wont render. I don't even see the map. How can I visualize the multipolygon using jinja2 or show the map if the list is empty?

{{ layers|tojson }} raises an TypeError.

This doesn't solve my issue since I don't get an SyntaxError:

[JavaScript raises SyntaxError with data rendered in Jinja template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555383/javascript-raises-syntaxerror-with-data-rendered-in-jinja-template)

BONUS: Is there an easy way to generate a new color for each polygon?

EDIT:

`layers` is defined inside the flask app server.py:

```
@app.route('/<path:subpath>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def show_subpath(subpath):
    poly = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': []
        }
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = request.form
            layers = []
            for key in data:
                if key == 'schulen':
                    poly['geometry']['coordinates'] = coords1
                    layers.append(poly)
                if key == 'boulderhallen':
                    poly['geometry']['coordinates'] = coords2
                    layers.append(poly)
            return render_template('/map.html', layers=layers)
    return render_template(subpath)
```

`coords1` and `coords2` look like mentioned above.

Comment: There's something missing here - where is `layers` defined?

Comment: Right! See Edit please.